# How to truncate string value in c#?

Tags: c#, formatting

I have a string that is of the format:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN-OOOOOO
```

how do i truncate the string value to be of the following in c#?

```
ABCDKLMNOOOOOO
```

Hope for advise

Comment: do you have other string that has the same length with this one `ABCDEFGHIJKLMN-OOOOOO`?

Comment: Look into string.Replace or Regex that will match a certain pattern like Richard mentioned.

Comment: -1 Not only have you not tried anything, you have only given one example, so how are we at all supposed to derive a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I will take a guess at the logic rules.  How about:

```
 string newStr = str.Substring(0,4)+str.Substring(10,4)+str.Substring(15,6);
```

or maybe you want

```
 string newStr = str.Substring(0,4)+str.Substring(10,4)+str.Split("-")[1];
```

there are many things you could want

Comment: +1 That would be my guess as well. Doesn't really help anybody though.

Comment: I would have suggested `String.Join("", str.Split("-"))`

Comment: @RichardSchneider - Except that would have given different results than listed.  But thanks for the -1